# Apache2 only displays "IT WORKS!" page?

Tags: networking, server, apache2, ip

So I set up an Apache2 server and have a domain name through [www.noip.com](http://www.noip.com%20noip) and for whatever reason it only displays the "it works!" page, no matter what my configuration files are. a similar question was asked here:[Simliar question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/338718/apache-server-virtual-host-not-working).

So is there a way to modify his solution to allow for me to just add pages without always modifying my IP request?

Not sure if it matters or not but none of the links in the "it works!" work either, they all give a "requested URL /(page name) not found."

Comment: Shouldn't you replace the default html file with the content that you want? Ususally in /var/www/html/index.html

Comment: @meccooll yes, though in this case I'm trying to use _[Ampache](http://ampache.org/)_, which still isn't recognized by **Apache** even with the correct .conf file.